# What is the easiest way to design Java Swing GUIs in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, ide

I've been coding basic UIs in Java manually and using NetBeans, but recently switched to Eclipse Indigo. I use the visual class builder to design SWT user interfaces in Eclipse but found out that it's painfully slow and laggy. It takes about four seconds for a change to be displayed and it's virtually impossible to build complex and large UIs with it effectively. Is this its usual behavior and is this the preferred way of building a Java Swing GUI in Eclipse?

Comment: Are you talking about WindowBuilder or some other plugin for visual design?

Comment: I use the [Visual Editor](http://wiki.eclipse.org/VE) for SWT but yes the lag is there

Comment: The VisualEditor project is dead. Use WindowBuilder instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Google aquired Instantiations and then donated [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) to **Eclipse** foundation it is the preferred free, open source visual GUI editor for **Swing, SWT and GWT**.

[image]

Comment: Note that WindowBuilder is included in the recent versions of the **Eclipse IDE for Java Developers** package, but not in the other packages available on the main downloads page. If you have one of those other packages, you'll have to install WB via **Help > Install New Software**.

Comment: I was talking about the WindowBuilder for Swing and SWT as shown in the above image. The problem is, to come up with a interface similar to the one shown in the image, it would take at least half-an-hour of work to simply drag and drop the components. I was just wondering whether it was something to do with my PC's performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Jigloo](http://www.cloudgarden.com/jigloo/).

Their eclipse update site it, http://cloudgarden.com/update-site

I have used it in windows quite well. But when I use it in mac, most of the time it crash.

But windows builder seems better to me.