# Which one works faster a program created by GUI builder or a program writed by codes without GUI builder?

Tags: java, netbeans

İ want to design a interface, i see there are two options:
1- using automatically created codes (but there will be a lots of codes)(using gui builder)
2- Directly write codes yourself, (at the end there will be less codes than method one)

Comment: if i can't explain the question, please don't give me any negative feedback, let me make it clear.

Comment: Please rephrase your question again !! unable to get what you want to ask

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196933/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-design-java-swing-guis-in-eclipse-ide)

Comment: That wont change anything.

Comment: For anyhing but a quickly thrown-together prototype, you'll *have to* write code yourself. Generated code is unmaintainable.

Comment: @Neeraj Jain which one works faster?

Comment: @Murat , it's not about which will work faster ,using Darg and Drop will save your development time if deadline is near , but if you are at learning stage code your self

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're asking which would be faster to use?

It depends on the experience of the programmer. If you have no experience in coding a UI then using a GUI builder/form builder would be the fastest and easiest way to get it done.

That being said it doesn't hurt to know how to code one without the help of a builder. :)

Comment: thank you for your answer. But at the end, which one works faster? a program that is created Using GUİ builder or dricetly writing codes.

Comment: @Murat There's no general answer to that question.